# Wrapped headers background color?

Tags: tabulator

I have a `Tabulator` table with this `CSS` styling for the headers:

```css
.mytabulator.green .tabulator-header
                   .tabulator-col {
    background: #92d050;
}
.mytabulator.wrapped-headers .tabulator-header
                             .tabulator-col
                             .tabulator-col-content
                             .tabulator-col-title {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Which makes the headers look like this:

[image]

... but how do I also style the header background green?
By background I mean this part:

[image]

I have tried multiple "Column & header" selectors and nothing works.

Thanks,
Matic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a background colour to the `tabulator-header` element too:

```css
.mytabulator .tabulator-header, .mytabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {
    background: #92d050;
}
```